# Yii2 + backbone

Tags: php, javascript, yii2, backbone.js

Проект на `Yii2`. К конкретному view подключаю скрипты `Backbone.js`.
Получается что пользователь авторизован через yii2, но backbone о пользователе ничего не знает.
Имеется отдельное API этого сервера.

Так вот **вопрос**:
как на стороне `Backbone` понять какой пользователь авторизован на сайте?
Я подключаю backbone в странице index [view] и  обращаюсь к API сервера длятого чтобы получить данные, но по сути я так жедолжен передать в заголовке запроса идентификатор пользователя

> access_token

. Как быть? Как его получить не проходя авторизацию через backbone, а передать его на прямую от yii приложения?

Answer (score 2):

1. На сервере всегда проверяем - авторизирован пользователь или нет. Во всех API которые этого требуют.
2. Что бы проверить на стороне клиента авторизацию, достаточно отдать в шаблоне index.html объект с флагом auth.

Пример

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      var settings = {
            auth: {{ User.authorized() }}
          };
    </script>
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

Ваш сервер генерирует HTML, вот он и поставит флаг.
Строка -> {{ User.authorized() }} написана как пример для шаблонизатора Twig

А в бекбоне вы проверяете

```js
if (settings.auth) {
  // Send request to server side
}
```

Этого хватит полностью покрыть ваши требования.